# How to close the menu - cuppa-ng2-slidemenu

Tags: html, angular

I am using this [angular ng2 slide menu library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuppa-ng2-slidemenu). Can you please suggest me how to close the menu after selecting any item.

The configuration says there is an option. Not sure how to configure the value.

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: documentation says, use **closeOnCLick** to close the menu as soon as an item is selected.` by default  false`

Comment: thanks. where and how do I update the closeOnCLick?

Answer (score 1):

**as per [angular ng2 slide library documentation](https://cuppalabs.github.io/components/slidemenu/)**
 in your template you add **config** attribute, like

```
<cuppa-slidemenu 
   [menulist]="menuItemsArray" 
   [config]="config"
   (open)="onMenuOpen()"   
   (close)="onMenuClose()"     
   (onItemSelect)="onItemSelect($event)">
</cuppa-slidemenu>
```

and in your ts file, you can define `config`, as shown in documentation.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  config = {
    closeOnCLick: true
  };
}
```

here is a **[live working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4artdk)**